# Reference a function in a Wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I would like to link to the edit post interface in Wordpress with the string to display being the post title. Cannot get it to work have tried any syntax that I could come up with, but I am also only 2 days into php.

Here is what I came up with. It creates a link but does not display the post title.

```
<a href=<?php edit_post_link('<?php echo get_the_title($ID);?>'); ?> </a>
```

[Edit post link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link)  ,  [Get title link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Comment: This question should go on wordpress.stackexchange.com to be seen by people who can answer it.

Comment: thanks, this was my first post here.

Comment: @OllieJones, IMO, it has nothing to do with WordPress, it's simply PHP being wrongly used. User2962925, the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) is your friend ;) Also, read other people's themes to see how they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) should not be used as href attribute. Try the following:

```
<?php edit_post_link( get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>
```